# Google App Script - how to Copy Paste values ( only non empty cells) of a data range with , from a Spreadsheet to another Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Objective - To copy all non-empty cells from a [Spreadsheet-1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DZX1Jb4qwCHETtAENIsRioJvl4TC0hUWZDn_k1q3oes/edit?usp=sharing) to [Spreadsheet-2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HptKwYzdWCsz9oey9hOouhWNTQ3GAyu9oswZ1xgP3D0/edit?usp=sharing).

I saw some codes online and modified for my use, sharing below.
I need help in getting the script right so that a variable range(i.e. to selects non-empty up to last rows and last columns) can be selected and data copied to [Spreadsheet-2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HptKwYzdWCsz9oey9hOouhWNTQ3GAyu9oswZ1xgP3D0/edit?usp=sharing).
I am trying to make it workable for '**A1:GZ1000**' range.
If numbers of rows / cols with non-zero (non-empty) increases, script needs to update range for passing values to [Spreadsheet-2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HptKwYzdWCsz9oey9hOouhWNTQ3GAyu9oswZ1xgP3D0/edit?usp=sharing).

''''

```
   function dataImport(ssaID, ssbID) {
  // source doc
  var ssaID         = '1DZX1Jb4qwCHETtAENIsRioJvl4TC0hUWZDn_k1q3oes' ;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssaID);



  var ssbID         = '1HptKwYzdWCsz9oey9hOouhWNTQ3GAyu9oswZ1xgP3D0' ;
  
  // source sheet
  var ss = sheet.getSheetByName('Data - Price');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  // Logger.log(SData) 

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssbID);
  
  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Data - Price');

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({ contentsOnly: true });
  Logger.log(SRange.length);
  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  var tsRange = ts.getRange(1,1,SRange.length,SRange[0].length);
  tsRange.setValues(Sdata);

}
```

''''
Pl. do ask for details if you require.

R U

Comment: The method `getDataRange()` gets you the max area that contains all non-empty cells of the sheet. As soon as your source sheet changes the area changes accordingly automatically. And you don't need the `var A1Range...` line as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hello Yuri, Curious to know.. Why dataRange is picking range upto last row, whereas numeric / string data is limited to row no. 264.

Comment: It's need to look on the sheet. What do you mean 'last row'? How do you define the lastness? Sometimes cells looks empty, but it isn't empty. Sometimes even the cell borders can make the method `getDataRange()` to include the cell into the 'data area'.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function dataImport(ssaID, ssbID) {
  var ssaID = '1DZX1Jb4qwCHETtAENIsRioJvl4TC0hUWZDn_k1q3oes';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssaID);
  var ssbID = '1HptKwYzdWCsz9oey9hOouhWNTQ3GAyu9oswZ1xgP3D0';
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Data - Price');
  var rg = sh.getDataRange();
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssbID);
  var tsh = tss.getSheetByName('Data - Price');
  tsh.clearContents();
  tsh.getRange(1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```